# How to fetch 5th and 6th day of every month in Unix?

Tags: shell, date, unix

Is it possible to fetch 5th and/or 6th day of every month in Unix?

I've tried this but it does not give me the desired output:

```
echo $((($(date +%-d)-1)/5))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for: i am assuming you want to get the 5th(or 6th) day of a month sitting on any day. If so, you can make use of the current date and get the 5th day of current month like below:

```
dd=`date '+%d'`
if(( $dd > 5 )); then
    (( diff = dd - 5 ))
     myDate=`date -d "-$diff days"`
else
    (( diff = 5 - dd ))
     myDate=`date -d "+$diff days"`
fi

echo $myDate
```

For 6th day you can do similarly. Above code should work on Linux distro.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
for month in {1..12}; do date -d "$month/5/2017" +"%c - is a %A"; done
```

Output:

```
Thu 05 Jan 2017 12:00:00 AM CET - is a Thursday
Sun 05 Feb 2017 12:00:00 AM CET - is a Sunday
Sun 05 Mar 2017 12:00:00 AM CET - is a Sunday
Wed 05 Apr 2017 12:00:00 AM CEST - is a Wednesday
Fri 05 May 2017 12:00:00 AM CEST - is a Friday
Mon 05 Jun 2017 12:00:00 AM CEST - is a Monday
Wed 05 Jul 2017 12:00:00 AM CEST - is a Wednesday
Sat 05 Aug 2017 12:00:00 AM CEST - is a Saturday
Tue 05 Sep 2017 12:00:00 AM CEST - is a Tuesday
Thu 05 Oct 2017 12:00:00 AM CEST - is a Thursday
Sun 05 Nov 2017 12:00:00 AM CET - is a Sunday
Tue 05 Dec 2017 12:00:00 AM CET - is a Tuesday
```

For the 6th of the month, it's done in a similar way.